# File Transfer Plugin ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

I am trying to download a song when i click a button.

here is my .ts file.

```
download() {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
    const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
    let url = 'http://think-digital.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/varla-varla-vaa.mp3';
    fileTransfer.download(url, cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'file.mp3').then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry);
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, (error) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
  }
```

i am getting error like this

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

what mistake i am doing

Comment: is cordova declared globally?

Comment: Yes it is declared above the @component

Comment: have you installed https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/ or https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file?

Comment: yes when i try to install it said that it is already installed

Comment: do `ionic state save` remove your plugins folder and do `ionic state restore`

Comment: @suraj i tried this now and deployed but same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137828/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-suraj).

Comment: try to import File from ionic native and do File.dataDirectory

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because of this line: `... cordova.file.dataDirectory ...`, since cordova is not defined, you can't access the `file` property from undefined. Try by adding this on top of the file: `declare var cordova: any;`

And please make sure you're running that part of the code only when it's a movile device, because cordova is not available when running the app in the browser

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        ... your code 
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I did that after giving that only I got this error I declared my car cordova above my @component

Comment: Are you getting that error when running the app in a physical device?

Comment: Are you waiting for the platform to be ready before executing that code?

Comment: Yes as you can see my question I have given platform read function

Comment: Wat I have not tried using if condition wait after that I will tell you

Comment: i have tried that one but i am still getting this error `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined`

Comment: Can you set a `debugger` inside the `download()` method, and check if cordova is defined? I get something like this when doing the same: https://gyazo.com/3b7255e3adab41ea85cb0ff830f3d2be

Comment: i tried in a  new project and it worked my success callback of the `console.log(entry)` gave this `download complete: {"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"file.mp3","fullPath":"/file.mp3","fil‌​esystem":"<FileSystem: files>","nativeURL":"file:///data/user/0/com.ionicframework.downloadaudio640291/‌​files/file.mp3"}`

Comment: I guess you can try by re-installing the plugins again in the old project and see if it works then

Comment: I am not able find the file.mp3 file in my mobile do you have any idea where it will be placed on seeing the above objrct

Comment: How to get ionic2 offical website i am getting only ionic3 website in docs is there any way i can look for ionic2 file plugin